# If i use reverselayout, the recent chats shows top of the chat screen. How to show the recent messages at the bottom above input box. (like wapp)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I am using recyclerview to show the list of chats in the chat screen. (Android java)

After rendering the chat messages, I need to scroll down to see the last message. So I have added
the below line. But it shows the old message above the input box.

But it needs to show the recent message above the input box in android.

Also the recyclerview is a list, I am getting all in a same adapter. If I try to set right and left message, it shows all the messages in the right side.

```
linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);  linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
```

Comment: remove this line `linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);`

Comment: Just set linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(false);  linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(false);

Comment: If I set the above values to false. I need to scroll down to see the last message in the recyclerview of the android. How can i make this to show the last message above the textinput then.